# How to use values from SAS table to create vertical reference lines in a graphic

Tags: plot, graphics, sas

A little bit of background first, I am currently working with a SAS script that creates graphics showing the changes in DVI (Difference Vegetation Index) over a certain period of time for different regions and for different types of crops.

For hay, I want to add vertical lines to the graphic showing when it was mowed during that period of time. In the table containing the variables used to create the graphics (day, DVI, region) there is also a variable containing the days where the hay got mowed.

I know that I can use href = X in proc gplot, but how can I use the values in my table  so that it creates vertical lines based on the time of mowing for each region?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create macro-variable, which pass a value from data to the graph e.g `call symputx` routine.

Comment: You are much more likely to get a response if you provide the simplest possible code that will generate a chart like the one you are trying to build.  I suggest using a datasource from the sashelp libname so that other people are also able to run the code on their machines.